# Visual Studio Team Services build cannot find .sln files

Tags: tfs, azure-devops

I am new to Visual Studio and Visual Studio Team Services.

I am trying to run a build on of simple code using Team Services. However, I get the following error:No solution was found using search pattern 'C:\a\1\s***.sln'.

My steps were:

1. In Team Services, create a team project, called Same New Project.
2. Open Visual Studio, configured my workspace.
3. In VS, created a new solution (Windows Form)
4. Checked in code.
5. In Team Services, selected Code from the menu and refreshed screen such that the new project.
6. Selected Build from menu.
7. Clicked on + sign to create a new build definition.
8. Selected Visual Studio. Clicked Next.
9. Checked Continuous integration (build whenever this branch is updated)
10. Selected Hosted under Default Agent Queue. Clicked Create.
11. See the image

[image]

12. Clicked Save.
13. Clicked Queue Build.
14. Clicked Ok.
15. After build completed, got posted error. 
    Here is the console output:
    Hosted Agent successfully assigned.
    Configuring connection settings for Hosted Agent
    Starting Hosted Agent
    Initializing connection to Hosted Agent
    Successfully connected to Hosted Agent

    ---

Starting: Build

---

Executing the following commandline:

> C:\LR\MMS\Services\Mms\TaskAgentProvisioner\Tools\agents\default\agent\worker\vsoWorker.exe  /name:Worker-1c2934a8-bfde-429a-945e-4bb6394a6d3b /id:1c2934a8-bfde-429a-945e-4bb6394a6d3b /rootFolder:"C:\LR\MMS\Services\Mms\TaskAgentProvisioner\Tools\agents\default" /logger:Forwarding,1.0.0;Verbosity=Verbose,Name=Agent1-1aadeebb9c4390e852d65e80b5fec753;JobId=1c2934a8-bfde-429a-945e-4bb6394a6d3b
>
> ---

Starting: Get sources

---

Syncing repository: Sam New Project (TFVC)

> Workspace Name: ws_1_1;Build\f1fca027-0a60-48e6-a5aa-f55071ee636c
>   Getting C:\a\1\s;C10
>   Getting C:\a\1\s\BuildProcessTemplates;C11
>   Getting C:\a\1\s\Sam New WIndows Form;C13
>   Getting C:\a\1\s\BuildProcessTemplates\AzureContinuousDeployment.11.xaml;C11
>   Getting C:\a\1\s\BuildProcessTemplates\DefaultTemplate.11.1.xaml;C11
>   Getting C:\a\1\s\BuildProcessTemplates\LabDefaultTemplate.11.xaml;C12
>   Getting C:\a\1\s\BuildProcessTemplates\UpgradeTemplate.xaml;C11
>   Getting C:\a\1\s\Sam New WIndows Form\Sam New WIndows Form;C13
>   Getting C:\a\1\s\Sam New WIndows Form\Sam New WIndows Form\App.config;C13
>   Getting C:\a\1\s\Sam New WIndows Form\Sam New WIndows Form\Form1.cs;C13
>   Getting C:\a\1\s\Sam New WIndows Form\Sam New WIndows Form\Form1.Designer.cs;C13
>   Getting C:\a\1\s\Sam New WIndows Form\Sam New WIndows Form\Program.cs;C13
>   Getting C:\a\1\s\Sam New WIndows Form\Sam New WIndows Form\Properties;C13
>   Getting C:\a\1\s\Sam New WIndows Form\Sam New WIndows Form\Sam New WIndows Form.csproj;C13
>   Getting C:\a\1\s\Sam New WIndows Form\Sam New WIndows Form\Sam New WIndows Form.csproj.vspscc;C13
>   Getting C:\a\1\s\Sam New WIndows Form\Sam New WIndows Form\Properties\AssemblyInfo.cs;C13
>   Getting C:\a\1\s\Sam New WIndows Form\Sam New WIndows Form\Properties\Resources.Designer.cs;C13
>   Getting C:\a\1\s\Sam New WIndows Form\Sam New WIndows Form\Properties\Resources.resx;C13
>   Getting C:\a\1\s\Sam New WIndows Form\Sam New WIndows Form\Properties\Settings.Designer.cs;C13
>   Getting C:\a\1\s\Sam New WIndows Form\Sam New WIndows Form\Properties\Settings.settings;C13
>   Done syncing repository Sam New Project to version C13 (workspace version C13)
>
> ---

Running tasks

---

---

Starting task: Build solution ***.sln

---

Executing the powershell script:

> C:\LR\MMS\Services\Mms\TaskAgentProvisioner\Tools\agents\default\tasks\VSBuild\1.0.19\VSBuild.ps1
>   No solution was found using search pattern 'C:\a\1\s***.sln'.
>
> ---

Finishing task: VSBuild

---

---

Starting task: Copy Files to: $(build.artifactstagingdirectory)

---

Set workingFolder to default:

> C:\LR\MMS\Services\Mms\TaskAgentProvisioner\Tools\agents\default\tasks\CopyFiles\1.0.10
>   found 0 files
>
> ---

Finishing task: CopyFiles

---

---

Starting task: Publish Artifact: drop

---

Set workingFolder to default:

> C:\LR\MMS\Services\Mms\TaskAgentProvisioner\Tools\agents\default\tasks\PublishBuildArtifacts\1.0.25
>   Max Concurrent Uploads 2, Max Creators 1
>   Found 0 files to upload.
>   Created 0 files without uploading content. Total files processed 0
>   Uploaded artifact 'C:\a\1\a' to container folder 'drop' of build 7.
>   Associated artifact 6 with build 7
>
> ---

Finishing task: PublishBuildArtifacts

---

Task VSBuild failed. This caused the job to fail. Look at the logs for the task for more details.

---

Finishing Build

---

> Worker Worker-1c2934a8-bfde-429a-945e-4bb6394a6d3b finished running job 1c2934a8-bfde-429a-945e-4bb6394a6d3b

Comment: Can you share the screenshot of the settings for "Repository" tab in your build definition?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the logs from "Get sources" step, solution file (.sln) isn't downloaded. Please check following things:

1: Go to "Code" tab and make sure the solution folder and file has been checked in.

2: Go to "Build" tab and make sure the "Mappings" under "Repository" setting include the solution folder in your build definition. [image]

Comment: Hi Eddie. Thanks for responding. The screenshot shown above is what I have in the Repository tab. I made the folder and files were checked in, and then reran the Build. I still got the same error. When looking at the files in the folder structure, there are no files with .sln. However, they are on my local workspace.

Comment: @SamShepard Then you need to add the sln file into Version Control. Can you check from Visual Studio\Team Explorer\Pending Changes\Excluded Changes to see if the solution file is been excluded?

Comment: They were excluded. I will check them in.

Comment: @SamShepard Can you mark it as answer if it works? :)